# How do I fix pip on mac?

Tags: python

By usin pip install simpleaudio I get the following:

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting simpleaudio
Using cached simpleaudio-1.0.4.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lc/wc3y14_d4vvbg6jf40sjnd140000gn/T/pip-install-FVBfFS/simpleaudio/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/lc/wc3y14_d4vvbg6jf40sjnd140000gn/T/pip-install-FVBfFS/simpleaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/lc/wc3y14_d4vvbg6jf40sjnd140000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-UA1xfJ
cwd: /private/var/folders/lc/wc3y14_d4vvbg6jf40sjnd140000gn/T/pip-install-FVBfFS/simpleaudio/
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/private/var/folders/lc/wc3y14_d4vvbg6jf40sjnd140000gn/T/pip-install-FVBfFS/simpleaudio/setup.py", line 42, in 
encoding='utf-8') as f:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: `pip` isn't broken. The message is telling you that the code you are trying to install is Python 3 and the Python 2 interpreter doesn’t accept it. You should not expect that 3rd party modules will necessarily support Python 2.

Comment: If I do python3 --version I get Python 3.9.7 so I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Do `pip --version` and see if that matches what you expect.

Comment: I get: pip 21.2.4 from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

Answer (score 1):

Though, I am a `Python` programmer with little experience. It sounds like your are still using `Python 2.7` which has been deprecated(not longer supported). To solve this, I recommend you go to [python.org](http://python.org) and then hover over the downloads button and then download the current version of Python.

Comment: If I do python3 --version I get
Python 3.9.7 so I don't know how to fix it